# Restrict chaincode acces - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'd like to know how I could do to restrict the access to a chaincode function for a particular client, is it possible to do it through the ACLs or maybe I should do it through the chaincode? 
Thanks & regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out ABAC (Attribute Based Access Control) of Hyperledger Fabric.

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABC-539

You can add extra fields/attributes to the x509 certificate of the user while registering/enrolling the user with the CA. Later while invoking, you can check for the attributes in the chaincode.

Comment: Thank you! That is very useful for me!
I have one more question: is it possible for a client who already has an ECert to access a function only once? That is, the client somehow requests an authorization (with certain information) that is verified by a third party (perhaps the CA) to execute the transaction only once.

Comment: I read about Tcerts, but I know that this functionality is no longer available in versions 1.0+

Answer (score 0):

If the access needs to be restricted based on whether the requester is member of a certain organization, then ABAC is not the right tool for that since anyone can put whatever attributes they want in their certificate. Not only that, it is possible to fake Organization too in the Subject header of X509 cert. In general, do not use metadata in the X509 certificate to determine whether requestor is part of an organization (e.g., there might be a chaincode method that should be restricted to users of your company). To test membership in an org, use the mspID returned by the ClientIdentity [[1](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.3/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html#getMSPID__anchor)]. That cannot be faked. If someone tries to fake it, there will be an error on the peers:

```
2019-05-16 16:12:49.132 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN c98 channel [mychannel]: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

ABAC can be used to restrict further access, but remember ABAC is not the right tool for restricting access based on membership in an org.

---

What is happening under the covers? When a chaincode is invoked e.g., using the [peer chaincode invoke](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-invoke-example) CLI, one of the environment variables that needs to be set is the `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` (if it is not set, fabric will use the value in the [core.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/sampleconfig/core.yaml) file). By setting this variable, the person invoking the chaincode is asserting that they are a member of the org in  `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID`. Then when request reaches the peer, the X509 cert provided by the person making the call is validated against the CA of the org they specified in the `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` variable. This validation is same as if one had run `openssl verify -CAfile ca.cert user.pem`. Now if the user tries to pretend to be a member of an org that they are not, the validation will fail with above message. Details on how a certificate is verified can be found [here](https://linuxctl.com/2017/02/x509-certificate-manual-signature-verification/). If the chaincode is being invoked using the node sdk, then the msp id is set in [network-config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/artifacts/network-config-aws.yaml) under `organizations -> org1 -> mspid`. Bottomline, if someone tries to fake it, it will result in error.